# Setting brightness of tv through cec-client

Tags: television

I am running cec-client on my linux machine and currently using it to turn off and on the TV. is there a command for seting the tv brightness??

I have a Samsung tv

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess there is no command to set brightness.

Check out all the supported commands here -

https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec/blob/master/src/testclient/main.cpp#L309-L347